# MouseMotionListener showing (x,y) offset

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, mouse-listeners

First of all, here is the related code:

```
    canvas = new CanvasPanel();
    canvas.setBackground(Color.white);
    canvas.addMouseListener(new PointListener());
    canvas.addMouseMotionListener(new PointListener());

    JSplitPane sp = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, leftPanel, canvas);


class CanvasPanel extends JPanel
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
    {
        super.paintComponent(page);

        if (mouseDragged == true)
        {
            page.drawRect(x1, y1, x3, y3);
            canvas.repaint();
        }
    }
}


class PointListener implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
{
    public void mousePressed (MouseEvent event)
    {
        mouseDragged = true;
        x1 = event.getX();
        y1 = event.getY();
    }
    public void mouseReleased (MouseEvent event)
    {
       // some code
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event)
    {
        x3 = event.getX();
        y3 = event.getY();
        canvas.repaint();
    }
```

So what this code is doing is when I click on the canvas component, it will draw an outline of a rectangle and the size changes as I drag the mouse

However, when I click and start to drag the mouse, there's an offset in the bottom right corner of the rectangle. It seems to jump to a bigger size the second I drag the mouse. Interestingly, the closer to the upper left corner of the canvas component I click, the closer the rectangle size is to the rectangle I draw with the mouse.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, `drawRect` uses `x`, `y`, `width`, `height` as it's parameters, you should actually be using the delta between the click point and the drag point

Maybe something like...

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
{
    super.paintComponent(page);

    if (mouseDragged == true)
    {
        int x = Math.min(x1, x3);
        int y = Math.min(y1, y3);
        int width = Math.max(x1, x3) - x;
        int height = Math.max(y1, y3) - y;
        page.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
    }
}
```

And, don't call `repaint` from within the `paint` methods

Comment: Oh duh : /. Thanks for that, I knew it was something stupid

Comment: It's probably unobvious from the answer, but `drawRect` doesn't accept negative width/height values ;)